# How to read table - TD content with htmlagilitypack - this table - TD has certain bacgkround image - xpath

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

With using htmlagilitypack i want to read text of certain TD. this td has certain background such as `image/acikustart.gif` with using htmlagilitypack c# how can i read this td content. this background exist only in 1 element and the page is so badly designed so i have to use this method :D

i mean table - tr - td

```
<td background="image/acikustart.gif" height="61" width="100%">
&nbsp;&nbsp;<font face = "Arial" size = "2" color = "black"><b>Hoparlörler 
- TÜM MARKALAR</b></font></td>
```

So from the above source code i will read : Hoparlörler - TÜM MARKALAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
//table/tr/td[@background = 'image/acikustart.gif']//text()
```